# A standard infinite abelian group consist of finite abelian groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $C_1 = \{ 1\}$, $C_2 = \{ 1, -1 \}$, $C_3 = \{1, \omega, \omega^2\}$, …, $C_n = \{x: x^n=1\}$, i.e $x$ is $n$th root of unity for fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers, then clearly under multiplication of complex number as binary operation, each $C_i$ is an abelian group of order $i$.

In fact, it is cyclic also. But I am not getting what will happen if we take a set $G$ which is union of all these $C_i$s, i.e., $G = \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, under same binary operation is also a group? And if yes then it is of infinite order?

Also what is the difference between saying $H =\{ x: x \text{ is $n$th root of unity for fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$}\}$ and $K =\{x: x\text{ is $n$th root of unity for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$}\}$?

Comment: Um, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry to say but I posted that by mistake initially without completing.Now I edited fully

Comment: Actually I am new user so still learning how to  use stackexchange. I will not repeat such mistakes again

Comment: Sir please review this question .Give me a chance

Comment: Your $G$ is a group of infinite order. In the last part of your question, the part with $K$ is fine (except that "belongs" should be "belonging") and defines your $G$. The part with $H$ should be "$H=\{x:x\text{ is }n\text{-th root of unity}\}$ for a fixed $n\in\mathbb N$."
 The point is that fixing $n$ is not part of the condition on $x$ for $x$ to get into $H$; rather it is a prerequisite to making sense of the actual condition $x^n=1$.

Comment: Okay, now my doubt is clear. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between
$$
C_n=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:x^n=1\}
$$
(for a fixed $n$) and
$$
K=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:x^n=1\text{ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$}\}
$$
The set $K$ is precisely the union
$$
K=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_n
$$
you want to investigate.

An analogy can be with $A_n=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:x\le n\}$
and $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$. Every set $A_n$ is finite, but their union is $\mathbb{N}$:
$$
\mathbb{N}=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:x\le n\text{ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$}\}
$$

However this is just an analogy for explaining the difference.

Why is $K$ a group? Suppose $x,y\in K$. Then $x^m=1$ for some $m$ and $y^n=1$, for some $n$. In particular
$$
(xy)^{mn}=x^{mn}y^{mn}=(x^m)^n(y^n)^m=1^n1^m=1
$$
so $xy\in K$. Also $1\in K$ and, if $x\in K$, also $x^{-1}\in K$ (why?). Since clearly $0\notin K$, we have that $K$ is a subgroup of the group $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ (with respect to multiplication, of course).

<sup>Note: I assume throughout that $0\notin\mathbb{N}$, as results from your notation.</sup>

This group is infinite. Indeed, if it were finite, say $K=\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}$, take for each $k$ a natural number $n_k$ such that $x_k^{n_k}=1$. Set $n=n_1n_2\dotsm n_k$: then $x_k^n=1$ for every $k$. Thus $K\subseteq C_n$, which is impossible, because $C_n$ does not contain all $2n$-th roots of unity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $G$ constructed in this way is a group. More generally, any [directed colimit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) (or even filtered colimit) of groups is computed in this way in terms of their underlying sets.

In fact, we can identify the group structure; there is an isomorphism

$$ \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to G : \frac{m}{n} \mapsto \exp\left( \frac{m}{n} 2 \pi i\right) $$

(check that this is well-defined!)

The inverse of this isomorphism can be expressed in terms of the complex argument function.